# While condition with document.querySelector don't working with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrap some information from Instagram, and I need an interval for my while condition to work fine(because the Instagram API doesn't load more content instantly, and my while picks an old value and finish). Still, my visual studio says that my function doesn't exist. That's my code:

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
require("dotenv").config();

let user = 'user';

let usernameToLogin = process.env.USERNAME_INSTAGRAM;
let passwordToLogin = process.env.PASSWORD_INSTAGRAM;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();



  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });
  
  await page.setViewport({
    width:1200,
    height:800
  });

  // Wait for log in form

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForSelector('[name="username"]'),
    page.waitForSelector('[name="password"]'),
    page.waitForSelector('[type="submit"]'),
  ]);

  // Enter username and password

  await page.type('[name="username"]', usernameToLogin);
  await page.type('[name="password"]', passwordToLogin);

  // Submit log in credentials and wait for navigation

  await Promise.all([
    page.click('[type="submit"]'),
    page.waitForNavigation({
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    }),
  ]);

  await page.goto(`https://www.instagram.com/${user}/followers/`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

await page.evaluate(async () =>{
  
  let contador = 0;
  while(document.querySelectorAll('._aaco').length != contador){ 
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('._aaco').length)
    contador = document.querySelectorAll('._aaco').length;
    console.log("contador é: "+contador)
    document.querySelector('._aano').scrollBy(0, 1000);
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500));
}

})

  const teste = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const followers = document.querySelectorAll("._aaco span");
    let followersArray = []
    followers.forEach((item) =>{
      followersArray.push(item.innerText)
    })
    return followersArray
  })

  console.log(teste)

  //await browser.close();
})();


/* while(document.querySelectorAll('._aaco').length != contador){ contador = document.querySelectorAll('._aaco').length;
        document.querySelector('._aano').scrollBy(0, 800)

} */
```

OBS: if I use the wait before wait function, the visual studio says "wait can be used only in top ...." because it is inside of page.evalute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use `page.exposeFunction` or simply inline the sleep logic in the browser, replacing `wait(500)` with `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500))` and make the callback `async`. If you do expose `wait`, you'll still need to `await` it when you call it. A lot of this code could be moved to Node/Puppeteer anyway--I'm not sure you _need_ to wait in the browser. `waitForFunction` is also useful here.

Comment: @ggorlen I've tried what you tell me, but the while function still stoping at the fist iteration.

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: Thanks. Please update the text as well, because now the error you're discussing doesn't relate to the code well. 500 is a pretty short timeout. The code seems OK--can you clarify how it's failing?

Comment: The while condition isn't working, but the condition is true when I try in browser console...